# Filter first row from specific grouped coulmn data

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Jane','Jane','Mike','Mike','Jane','Jane','Jane',
                           'Mike','Mike','Jane','Jane','Jane'],
                   'ctg':['A','P','C','B','B','C','B','E','G','L','M','X']})
```

expected output:

| name | ctg |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | A |
| Jane | B |
| Jane | L |

I am new in python and i want to make new Dataframe which includes only the first row of every 'Jane' name. could you please anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) on a custom group with a mask:

```
mask = df['name'].eq('Jane')

out = (df[mask]  # keep only Jane
        # group by consecutive names
       .groupby(df['name'].ne(df['name'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)
       .first()  # first row of each group
      )
```

output:

```
   name ctg
0  Jane   A
1  Jane   B
2  Jane   L
```

Comment: group on `.cumsum()` wow, the part where I got stuck

Comment: thank you for your answer but it shows key Error for 'Jane'.

Comment: @stefan I never use `Jane` except in testing the equality: `df['name'].eq('Jane')`. Please double-check you're running my exact code, this error doesn't make sense.

Comment: @mozway yes i have used exact your code but still same error.

Comment: I am sorry, I tested it again without error, did you use the example in your question? If not please provide the DataFrame

Comment: @mozway thank you for your support, it is working now. if possible, could you please update the answer for group by with two names in single coulumn(example: Jane, Mike)?  perhaps, this possibility will help others.

Comment: You should provide an updated example (if too different, then ask a new question)